# Whitespace preservation in LESS escaping for calc operands in CSS3

Tags: css, webkit, less, whitespace

I would like to express the following CSS in LESS:

```
.a {
    min-height: calc(2em + 4px);
}
```

So, in order to prevent LESS from attempting a computation, I've written the expression using the LESS [escaping syntax](http://lesscss.org/#-escaping):

```
.a {
    min-height: ~'calc(2em + 4px)';
}
```

However, LESS's minifying engine is removing the whitespace, and emitting:

```
.a{min-height:calc(2em+4px);}
```

This is problematic because webkit fails to properly compute `2em+4px`, whereas `2em_+_4px` works fine (underscores added for clarity.)  It seems that the real bug here is in webkit, as I would hope that the syntax of CSS3 calc allows there to not be whitespace between tokens.

Comment: I have a workaround, which is to simply use min-height: 2.5em, which for my purposes is good enough, but I'm still interested in knowing whether LESS provides this affordance.

Comment: goto less2css.org and paste in .a {
    min-height: ~'calc(2em + 4px)';
} - the output isn't minified - ie it looks like 2em_+_4px

Comment: @Danield, thanks, however in my case, I want to minify the output, just not a certain range of text... essentially I want a workaround for a particular minification.  I may just close this question since the issue is clearly in webkit, not LESS.

Comment: Don't know if it will resolve your issue, but [LESS 1.5 changes included a change in the minifier software they use](http://lesscss.org/#changes). If you haven't already, you might try it out.

Comment: FYI--the [specs for CSS3](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#calc-syntax) _do require_ whitespace around '+' and '-' operators, so it is not a webkit bug.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is kind of an old post but I wanted to show you a simple `mathematic` workaround for this.

I also have this issue with my minifying engine. Mine works fine with substraction but remove whitespace in addition. If someone have the same problem, this is the simplest workaround.

If you want this:

```
.a {
    min-height: ~'calc(2em + 4px)';
}
```

Write it as this instead:

```
.a {
    min-height: ~'calc(2em - -4px)';
}
```

Comment: Thank you! You saved our day! It's a bug in older YUI Compressor versions (before 2014). You need to write double minus instead of plus there. More info: https://github.com/yui/yuicompressor/issues/59 << We are still using the old version in core components of our web project.

Answer (score 1):

You must use "[escape](http://lesscss.org/functions/#string-functions-escape)" function applying it in a different way:

**FIRST OPTION**:

```
.a {
    min-height:calc(~"2em + " 4px);
}
```

**SECOND OPTION**:
Limiting use of escape character `~` only to `+` symbol:

```
.a {
    min-height:calc(2em ~"+" 4px);
}
```

*Both of them will result in the following processed CSS:*

```
.a {
    min-height: calc(2em + 4px);
}
```

Comment: Well, Will's problem was not in Less code but in a minifier which indeed produced invalid CSS (since whitespace are required by the spec. there).