# Why is less precomputing the viewport height in calc()?

Tags: less

I have a simple class in myfile.less that looks like this:

```
.myclass {
    width: calc(100vh - 50px);
}
```

I would assume that the compiled css output would look identical.  However, running "lessc myfile.less" outputs the following:

```
.myclass {
    width: calc(50vh);
}
```

Why is it making this change? 100% of the viewport height minus 50 pixels is not necessarily the same as 50% viewport height. I am using less v2.5.1 installed via npm, but also tried reverting to v1.7.5 and I get the same output.

Comment: Have a look at the [--strict-math](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage-options) option setting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to use "[escape](http://lesscss.org/functions/#string-functions-escape)" function as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19283380/whitespace-preservation-in-less-escaping-for-calc-operands-in-css3/28320535#28320535) to a similar question.

```
width:calc(100vh ~"-" 50px);
```