# LESS, compile issues

Tags: compiler-errors, less

I'm using `Visual Studio 2012` and `Web Essential 2012` and `Less` generates the `css` not as, as expected

```
//style.less

 .selector{
     max-height: calc(100vh - 200px)
 }
```

In the style.css it's generates something like this

```
//style.css
.selector{
      max-height: calc(-100vh);
}
```

**Any ideas?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Less Aggressive Compilation with CSS3 calc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972084/less-aggressive-compilation-with-css3-calc)

Comment: your answer also duplicated  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904088/disable-less-css-overwriting-calc)

Comment: You can check the dates to see which is a duplicate of which. That comment to which you linked says that the thread you linked is a dupe of the one I linked.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "[escape](http://lesscss.org/functions/#string-functions-escape)" function as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19283380/whitespace-preservation-in-less-escaping-for-calc-operands-in-css3/28320535#28320535) to a similar question.

```
.selector{
     max-height: calc(100vh ~"-" 200px);
}
```